# Why does position sticky not work without border on the parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Consider the following example:

```css
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

button {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <button>Sticky</button>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Position sticky is working as expected - no problem.

Now let's just remove the border from the container:

```css
.container {
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  /* border changed! */
}

button {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <button>Sticky</button>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

You can notice that the position sticky is no longer working. Why is that? Does border somehow affects the stacking context or scrollable area or something?

Comment: Hi! please try to add    " width: 100%;   float: left;" and remove border

Comment: That's ok guys, I've found the reason. It's just because of margin-collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

It may Help you :

```
.container {
border: 0px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
}
```

Or

```
    .container {
float: left;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
}
```